# Test loading message content before AJAX request is completed with Capybara

Tags: ajax, jquery, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I see a lot of questions and answers about Capybara not waiting for an AJAX request to complete before testing for content, but I need to do the opposite: I want to test that a loading message is present before the AJAX request is done.

How would I check content is shown before an AJAX request is done with Capybara in RSpec?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out...

If you want to check something right away without waiting for AJAX to finish, you just check the text with an include:

page.find('#id').text.should include('loading...')

If you do want to wait for AJAX to return you use have_content:

page.find('#id').should have_content('loaded')